# Создание списка по категориям

Tags: android, listview, activity

Хочу создать список с категориями, и когда человек выбирает нужную ему категорию, то ему открывается список элементов c `checkbox`-ами  той категории и человек может выбрать тот или иной элемент. Что мне нужно использовать для реализации данной идеи ? Использую Firebase.

Comment: Можно использовать ExpandablelistView:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php
https://habr.com/post/147546/

Comment: @YungBlade а я бы хотел,чтобы был список категорий, и при выборе категории открывалось окно со списком элементов данной категории. Можно использовать одно activity на эти действия ? Т.е. сначала открывается список категорий, после выбора категории, категории пропадают и появляется список элементов выбранной категории

Comment: Лучше после клика открывать вторую активность или диалоговое окно.

Comment: Да, все это можно и нужно сделать в одной активити. В Android Studio есть уже [готовый шаблон-проект](http://www.appstoremarketresearch.com/articles/android-tutorial-master-detail-flow/) такого решения - "Master Detail Flow", фактически вам нужно олько заполнить его своими данными